# Accesing UI thread with Async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I wonder which approach is better/cleaner:

Should I pass **Context** on the constructor and have **onPostExecute** access the UI thread?

or

**Extend** my Task class in the UI thread and override **onPostExecute** (no need to pass Context)?

Passing Context into AsyncTask feels 'dirty' but I don't know whether it's ok 'polluting' the UI class.

Comment: Why cant you just make it an inner class?

Comment: I like having my tasks in a separate file but yes, it's plausible :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use inner classes for this and see no reason why this should be a bad solution, assuming the class implementation is specific to the class into which it's nested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to extend your class in future with another class, then **extend** it. But I'd rather choose passing the context in the constructor.